# Need help parsing a csv JSON field to string with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to upload a kaggle movie [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset) using logstash into elasticsearch. The **genres** field is a stringified JSON object:

```
"genres" : "[{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 9648, 'name': 'Mystery'}, {'id': 53, 'name': 'Thriller'}]"
```

Is it possible to transform the value from the above to an array like so using logstash?

```
"genres"; ["Action", "Drama", "Mystery", "Thriller"]
```

I tried using the ***json*** filter, but no luck.

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "genres"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should convert json string to object, then handle this object to new object and convert new object to new json string.
Object: Gener `{ int id; string value; }`
Old Object:  `{ List<Gener> geners }` 
New Object: `{ List<string> geners }`

Comment: Hey Tran Manh Cam, I am trying to do it with logstash.